# How to use python to generate a magazine cover?

Tags: python, image, imagemagick

I'm looking for something that can generate a magazine cover with 
a image and I can add some content highlights on it. 
What's the best library to do this job?
Is it PIL? or imagemagick?

Comment: Please define "magazine cover".

Comment: Please define "generate", for that matter...

Comment: If you just want to superimpose some text onto an image, then PIL would work. I don't know much about ImageMagick. For more complex cases, you'd be better off with a proper DTP package.

Comment: In my case, magazine cover is a image, with highlights of content on top. @Tichodroma

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm surprised that you want to design a magazine cover programmatically, rather than with a GUI like Photoshop, Illustrator, Gimp, or Inkscape.  But, assuming that you do, I think the easiest way would be to use Python to construct an SVG image.  [SVG](http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/) is vector based (line positions can be modified after they have been made) and human-readable XML, so you can alternate between auto-generating graphics in Python and editing them by hand in [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/).  Python has good [built-in](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) and [third-party](http://lxml.de/) tools for manipulating XML, for which SVG is just a special case.

Generating an image programmatically will probably involve a lot of trial-and-error, so I recommend setting yourself up with an interactive viewer.  Here's a simple one using GTK (e.g. in Ubuntu, `apt-get install python-rsvg python-cairo`):

```
import cairo
import rsvg
import gtk

class Viewer(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.string = """<svg width="800" height="600"></svg>"""
        self.svg = rsvg.Handle(data=self.string)
        self.win = gtk.Window()
        self.da = gtk.DrawingArea()
        self.win.add(self.da)
        self.da.set_size_request(800, 600)
        self.da.connect("expose-event", self._expose_cairo)
        self.win.connect("destroy", self._destroy)
        self.win.show_all()
        self.win.present()

    def _expose_cairo(self, win, event):
        self.svg = rsvg.Handle(data=self.string)
        cr = self.da.window.cairo_create()
        self.svg.render_cairo(cr)

    def _destroy(self, widget, data=None):
        gtk.main_quit()

    def renderSVG(self, text):
        x, y, w, h = self.win.allocation
        self.da.window.invalidate_rect((0,0,w,h), False)
        self.string = text
```

Now you can build up graphics with commands like

```
viewer = Viewer()    # pops up a window
import lxml.etree as etree
from lxml.builder import E as svg

rectangle = svg.rect(x="10", y="10", width="80", height="80", style="fill: yellow; stroke: black; stroke-width: 2;")
circle = svg.circle(cx="70", cy="70", r="30", style="fill: red; fill-opacity: 0.5; stroke: black; stroke-width: 2;")

document = svg.svg(rectangle, circle, width="100", height="100")

viewer.renderSVG(etree.tostring(document))   # draws the image in the window
```

and save them with

```
open("outputFile.svg", "w").write(etree.tostring(document))
```

Bitmapped PNG images can be embedded in SVG by encoding them in an `href:data` attribute by encoding them with Base64.  That would require a long explanation, but I'm just letting you know that it's possible.  Also, SVG supports all of the glossy gradients and blending effects that you'd expect on a shiny magazine cover, but you'll have to dig into the documentation to see how it's done.

Comment: +1. This is the kind of thoughtful answer that needs more support on SO.

Comment: Thank you very much for such a comprehensive answer, this is exactly what I'm looking for.